# Tinymce показывает полный путь к серверу?

Tags: php, безопасность, tinymce

Cайт проверяется сторонним сервисом на уязвимости. Присылают отчет, ругается на `tinymce`. Куда копать?

Пишут в отчете:

> For Development:
>   Don't display fully qualified pathnames as part of error or informational messages. At the least, fully qualified pathnames can provide an attacker with important information about the architecture of web application.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Где на приведенном вами скриншоте полный путь?

Comment: Последняя строчка в request

Comment: Только сейчас вспомнила, что этот менеджер загрузки файлов не нативный, а стороннего разработчика. Походу, проще его удалить.